# Emacs ruby symbol word completion

Tags: ruby, emacs, autocomplete, symbols

Quite often I define a ruby symbol (eg. `:some_value`), then I want to create a method with the same name `def some_value`.

Unfortunately, the autocompletion(`M + /`) for the second occurrence of some_value string does not work, being slightly different (`:some_value` vs `some_value`).

How can I setup emacs to handle such events?

Comment: What exactly is M-/ mapped to for you? If it's dabbrev-expand, what's your value for dabbrev-abbrev-char-regexp?

Comment: Like 0x4b says, we need more information.  What ruby mode are you using?  RubyMode? MuMaMo-Mode?    FWIW, dabbrev completes for me just fine when the only other occurrence of the string is `:some_value`.

Comment: I'm using basic ruby-mode. I haven't change what M - / does. However what mode I'm using is quite irrelevant. It doesn't work in the 'scratch' buffer with no modes.

Comment: \*scratch\* actually is in lisp-interaction-mode by default. Could you please type in the following and tell us what Emacs writes to the minibuffer? C-h k M-/

Comment: What mode you're using is *VERY* relevant, for the mode sets up which symbols are word constituents, which are syntax, parens, etc.  Every buffer has a mode, it is impossible for Emacs to have a buffer without a mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that M-/ is bound to dabbrev-expand, you can configure dabbrev-mode to ignore certain prefixes when expanding strings. To make a single colon a prefix to be ignored, type

```
M-x customize-group
```

and then

```
dabbrev
```

This will take you to the customization page for dabbrev-mode. Go to the point **Dabbrev Abbrev Skip Leading Regexp** and click on `Value menu`. From the menu, pick "Regexp".

Now you see a textfield labeled "Regexp: " next to the value menu in which you enter a single colon.

```
:
```

Then click on the button `State` in the next line and choose the value "Save for Future Sessions".

Comment: Great tip! I extended it to only enable this in Ruby and Clojure modes: https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/10877484

Answer (score 2):

First, my results! I typed `:some_crazy_symbol` in my model. On a newline, I typed `def so`, hit `M-/` twice, and ended up with

```
def some_crazy_symbol
end
```

(Rinari supplied the `end`.)

I got this to work quite well by using `hippie-expand`. If you want to test it out, bind `hippie-expand` to `M-/` like so:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)
```

Heres' the [documentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand). Hippie expand works by trying out a number of different expansions on the current point. These expansions are stored in the `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` variable. On my system (and be default), this variable is set to:

`(try-complete-file-name-partially try-complete-file-name try-expand-all-abbrevs try-expand-list try-expand-line try-expand-dabbrev try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers try-expand-dabbrev-from-kill try-complete-lisp-symbol-partially try-complete-lisp-symbol)`

The minibuffer readout showed that this particular expansion was accomplished using the `try-expand-dabbrev` function.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you should get more intelligent Ruby autocompletion by using [auto complete mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) paired with [rsense](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't installed but rsense does look pretty sweet.

Answer (score 1):

If *Dabbrev Abbrev Skip Leading Regexp* and `hippie-expand` doesn't do exactly what you want and you've got some elisp skills, you could create a custom function for `hippie-expand`.

See the section about "[*substring expansion*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand#toc7)" on the *[hippie-expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand)* page on the emacs-wiki. There's a function you could use there you could tailor to customize..

> **[Substring Expansion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand#toc7)**
>
> When doing lisp programming standard dabbrev is less useful, because Emacs has no namespaces, so in a package symbols begin with the same prefix, therefore the same prefix has to be typed again and again if one wants to complete symbols from the package. As with IswitchBuffers it is much more effective if a unique substring can be typed to get to the desired symbol.
>
> Dabbrev offers nothing in this regard, so I turned to Hippie Expand which I had never used before.
>
> Here’s a function based on hippie expand dabbrev expansion which performs substring expansion:

```
(defun try-my-dabbrev-substring (old)
  (let ((old-fun (symbol-function 'he-dabbrev-search)))
    (fset 'he-dabbrev-search (symbol-function 'my-dabbrev-substring-search))
    (unwind-protect
        (try-expand-dabbrev old)
      (fset 'he-dabbrev-search old-fun))))


(defun my-dabbrev-substring-search (pattern &optional reverse limit)
  (let ((result ())
    (regpat (cond ((not hippie-expand-dabbrev-as-symbol)
               (concat (regexp-quote pattern) "\\sw+"))
              ((eq (char-syntax (aref pattern 0)) ?_)
               (concat (regexp-quote pattern) "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+"))
              (t
               (concat (regexp-quote pattern)
                   "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+")))))
    (while (and (not result)
        (if reverse
             (re-search-backward regpat limit t)
             (re-search-forward regpat limit t)))
      (setq result (buffer-substring-no-properties (save-excursion
                                                     (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                                                     (skip-syntax-backward "w_")
                                                     (point))
                           (match-end 0)))
      (if (he-string-member result he-tried-table t)
      (setq result nil)))     ; ignore if bad prefix or already in table
    result))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd share the [solution I came up with that works for `hippie-expand`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13098/264).

To summarize:

```
(defun hippie-expand-ruby-symbols (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if (eq major-mode 'ruby-mode)
      (let ((table (make-syntax-table ruby-mode-syntax-table)))
        (modify-syntax-entry ?: "." table)
        (with-syntax-table table (apply orig-fun args)))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'hippie-expand :around #'hippie-expand-ruby-symbols)
```

`hippie-expand` will expand symbols in `ruby-mode` when `:` is considered a punctuation character, so this advice creates a temporary syntax table where `:` is a punctuation character and calls `hippie-expand` with it.